# Greater/lesser than operators in Sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

Is there a way to compare Sequel.qualifys with other operators than =>?

I want to do like this, but that doesn't work. What is the proper way?

```
DB[:table1].graph(:table2, Sequel.qualify(:table2, :column1) > Sequel.qualify(:table1, :column1))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What SQL query are you trying to generate?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON ((table2.table1_id = table1.id) AND (table2.column1 > table1.column1));